# Converting connection string from Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb, oledbconnection

I am working with a .NET program that will at some point in the future be 64-bit compiled where Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 will not work.

I'm trying to convert this Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 connectionstring that looks like this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;OLE DB Services=-4;Password=<PASSWORD>;User ID=<USERID>;Data Source=<ACCESSDATABASE>.MDB;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:System database=<SYSTEMDB>.mdw"
```

to a Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 that looks something like:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<ACCESSDATABASE>.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=<PASSWORD>;Jet OLEDB:System database=<SYSTEMDB>.mdw;Persist Security Info=False"
```

Whenever I try to connect with this new connectionstring I get this exception:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E4D): Not a valid account name or password.
```

Anyone know how to properly convert this connectionstring so that it's valid? There is no documentation on Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 connection string parameters that I know of.

Comment: I just noticed after posting my answer below, you may need quotes around your `Data Source` if it contains spaces.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `ConnectionString` that I use for `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` and it works fine.

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
          Data Source="$LOCALAPPDATA$\Path\database.mdb";
          Persist Security Info=True;
          Jet OLEDB:Database Password=$PASSWORD$`

The only difference I can see in your `ConnectionString` is the specifying the system database. Maybe that database also has a password?